# Need denormalized query from heirarchial table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a table(lets name it HEIRARCHY_TABLE ) in this format representing hierarchical data where a tree is stored in this format.

```
HEIRARCHY_TABLE (parent_name ,parent_id     ,child_name ,child_id)
Sample Data in HEIRARCHY_TABLE:-
-------------------------------------------
parent_name |parent_id     |child_name |child_id
--------------------------------------------
parent_1  | parent_1_id   | leaf_node |  leaf_node_id1

parent_2   | parent_2_id   | parent_1  |  parent_1_id
```

the above scenario is showing data for a case where parent_2->parent_1->leaf_node
where -> representing "is parent of " relation-ship.

I need to query this table and get a result like this for all leaf nodes.
Result:-

leaf_node  |  parent_1  | parent_2  | parent_3 |parent_4  | parent_5 |parent_6  | parent_7

and if for suppose a leaf node has only two parents then i require the rest of the parent values to be null.
i.e..,if it has only 5 parents.then parent_6 and parent_7 should be null.
Note :- the above table contains multiple trees.hence it contain multiple roots.I need data for all the trees available in  this table in this format.the maximum level in all the trees is 7 only.

Comment: You are looking for Oracle?

Comment: yes.i am looking for a oracle sql query

Answer (score 0):

The fastest query would be to use [heirarchy IDs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/bb677290.aspx). then you can query against all or part of a tree using CONTAINS on the heirarchy id column.

Of course this assumes you are allowed to/can build this column.

For oracle, you can do Heirarchy Query. Not sure about its efficiency/demormalization factor. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm

Comment: As you have suggested me i have tried this sql query:-SELECT parent_name,
  parent_id,
  child_id,
  child_name,
  LEVEL,
  SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(child_name, '/') "Path"
FROM fusion_role_heirarchies a
WHERE not exists(select 1 from fusion_role_heirarchies b where b.parent_name=a.child_role )
  CONNECT BY PRIOR child_id = parent_id
  
ORDER SIBLINGS BY child_name;


But this is returning for all records (leaf,non-leaf nodes).I want this only for non leaf nodes.

Comment: thanks a ton for your timely help.I have done it with CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF

Answer (score 0):

Google around for Common Table Expressions. What you are looking for, I think, is a recursive query. You are going to have to play some games to force the query to return nulls for parents that don't actually exist. [Check this.] (http://www.morganslibrary.org/reference/with.html)

Comment: I tried with this sql as you have suggested me :-

select count(*)
FROM HEIRARCHY_TABLE a ,
  HEIRARCHY_TABLE b ,
  HEIRARCHY_TABLE c,
  HEIRARCHY_TABLE d,
  HEIRARCHY_TABLE e,
  HEIRARCHY_TABLE f,
  HEIRARCHY_TABLE g
WHERE b.child_id =a.parent_id
AND c.child_id (+) =b.parent_id
AND d.child_id  (+) =c.parent_id
AND e.child_id  (+) =d.parent_id
AND f.child_id   (+)=e.parent_id
AND g.child_id   (+)=f.parent_id;

this is multiplying the exisiting data.if i have 100 odd records. this sql is giving me 2000 odd records.can you please help me where i am getting it wrong